# For transformations from $F^n \rightarrow F^m$ does $T(u)=[T]_\beta^\gamma (u)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am currently studying linear algebra and there is a proof that goes as follows:

> Theorem 2.14. Let V and W be finite-dimensional vector spaces having ordered bases $\beta$ and $\gamma$, respectively, and let $T:V \rightarrow W$ be linear. Then, for each $u∈V$, we have
> $$[T(u)]_\gamma=[T]_\beta^\gamma[u]_\beta$$

I am wondering if we are working with tuples, where the transformations are from  $F^n \rightarrow F^m$, can we extrapolate from the theorem that: $T(u)=[T]_\beta^\gamma *u$?

Answer (score 1):

No, not necessarily. We could take, for example,
\begin{align*}
T\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix} y \\ x \end{bmatrix} \\
\beta, \gamma &= \left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\right) \\
u &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
T\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = -1\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + 1\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
T\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = 0\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + 1\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Thus,
$$[T]_\beta^\gamma = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Now, we have
$$Tu = T\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix},$$
but
$$[T]_\beta^\gamma u = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} \neq T(u).$$